# Copying EGenericType instances with ECoreUtil.Copier

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I am working with EMF models and need to make copies of these. My models consist of interlinked instances of three meta-models, one of which is Ecore itself. So far, so good.

However, when it comes to copying these models (which I do using `EcoreUtil.Copier.copyAll` following the usual protocol), some parts of my model are not copied. Specifically, the Ecore instance contains a number of instances of `EGenericType` (because there are references and attributes and these are automatically set up with `EGenericType` instances to show their types). The result of copying contains everything, but these instances of `EGenericType`.

I have searched high and low and looked into the EMF source code, too, but couldn't figure out what the problem is. I have looked at the source of `EcoreUtil.Copier` and it checks for each structural feature whether it is changeable and not derived to decide whether to actually copy it. This condition is true for the reference to `EGenericType`, so this should be copied as a containment reference.

Interestingly, the result of the copy **does** contain copied instances of `EGenericType` in all the right places in the object graph. However, these are not mapped in the copier, so don't seem to have been created by a call to `EcoreUtil.Copier.copy` along the way, but implicitly.

Any ideas when these are created and how I might get them to show up in the copier map?

Many thanks,

Steffen

Answer (score 2):

OK, so I have dug deeper into this with the debugger and think I now understand what's going on:

Essentially, `ETypedElement` (which is what contains types and generic types) is a bit loose with its contract: neither `eType` nor `eGenericType` are marked as derived, but depending on the situation, they one of them will be derived from the other.

Specifically, if you set the `eType` of an `ETypedElement`, this implicitly creates a new `eGenericType`. Similarly, if you set the `eGenericType`, this will implicitly set the `eType` to be the erasure of this generic type.

Unfortunately, this behaviour confuses `EcoreUtil.Copier` when an `ETypedElement` has had its `eType` set explicitly. In this situation, the following happens:

1. `EcoreUtil.Copier.copy` creates a new instance of the `ETypedElement` and then starts copying all of its features.
2. When it gets to the `eType` feature, it doesn't copy it at this point, because `eType` is not a containment reference (for obvious reasons).
3. Next it comes to `eGenericType`, which is a containment reference. However, the first thing it does is to check whether this is set in the original `ETypedElement`. For `eGenericType` and `eType`, this check has been customised to make sure only one of the two actually returns `true`. As a result, for our `ETypedElement`, `isSetEType()` returns `true` and `isSetEGenericType()` returns `true`. Therefore, `copyContainment()` decides there is nothing to copy and moves on.
4. By the time `copy()` or `copyAll()` returns, neither the `eType` nor the `eGenericType` have been set for the newly created object. We now call `copyReferences()`.
5. This will eventually attempt to copy the `eType` reference (remember that this is marked as not a containment reference). `isSetType()` returns `true`, so `copyReference()` goes on and copies the type information across. The setter for `eType` in the copied object then creates the new instance of `EGenericType`, but `EcoreUtil.Copier` never gets to see it.

Thus, if I want to get the original `EGenericType` instance and its copy to show up in the copy map, I will need to sub-class `EcoreUtil.Copier` and override `copyReference()` or `copyContainment()` to handle this special case.